# Transport Gmail label to Zimbra

Tags: gmail, import, zimbra

I have several hundreds of emails in a Gmail label which I want to forward to Zimbra. I want to do this systematically, just like the "Accounts and Import" in Gmail, so that making those emails in that Gmail label to my Zimbra email account, leaving the original mailing time and the sender unchanged (rather than showing a new time with sender my Gmail account).

Any body know how to do this in an easy way?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can connect Zimbra to your Google account using IMAP and migrate that way: https://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Mail_Migration.

If you have 2-factor auth turned on, you'll need to turn on Less Secure Apps in your security settings and create and app password.

You could also export your Gmail messages with Google Takeout, and use one of the scripts farther down on that page to import messages that way.